# i want to add bootsnipp slider in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, slider

Here is my main view page :
the first class: item active ,
and another is only class: item 
but i want foreach only class="col-sm-6" with two class item active and item ...

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-item">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="img/a.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="price col-md-6">
                                <h5>title</h5>
                                <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                    Contact for price</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> <b>3</b>
                                <i class="fa fa-bath"></i> <b>2</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="separator clear-left">
                            <p class="btn-details">
                                <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-item">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="2.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="price col-md-6">
                                <h5>title</h5>
                                <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                    Contact for price</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> <b>5</b>
                                <i class="fa fa-bath"></i> <b>3</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="separator clear-left">
                            <p class="btn-details">
                                <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but when i foreach the div one is active class but i want one div is active but another is not . actually i want to foreach col-sm-6 class.. how to do this. first

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the following:

1. for there to be one active item
2. for each `item` to contain several `col-sm-6` elements, created via a `php` `foreach` loop
3. create `item` via a `php` `foreach` loop

   ```
   <!-- language: lang-php -->
   <?php $active_item = "active" ?>
   <?php foreach($itemlist as $item): ?>
       <div class="item <?php echo $active_item ?>">
       <?php $active_item = "" ?>
           <div class="row">
               <?php foreach($item as $column): ?>
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <!-- insert your logic here for creating your columns in a carousel -->
                   </div>
               <?php endforeach ?>
           </div>
       </div>
   <?php endforeach ?>
   ```

`$active` will append the `active` class to only the first instance of your carousel items.

I avoided using `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` and checking the key for whether the item is to be active, as your array may not have numerical keys that begin with 0.

Comment: thanks @SylphFeather ,, but i want first two post into active class... another is into another class